# Magento 1.7.0.2 Supee 5994 error

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm having problems installing the latest security patch Supee 5994 and have been scouring to find an error like mine however I haven't found one. The error I'm getting is this:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php.rej
patching file   
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
```

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestion for me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not experience in Magento, however I was able to find this link which has several ways listed that have worked for other users to solve this issue: http://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/SUPEE-5994-appears-to-patch-nothing-on-magento-1-7-0-2/td-p/5867/page/2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution. I also found another source just in case anyone needs it. The direct link to download the source files is:

https://www.milople.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SUPEE-5994-1.7.0.2.zip

Once downloaded, you will have to unzip the folder and navigate to the "SUPEE-5994-1.7.0.2\" directory. Once there, you will have to drag and drop all contents to your magento directory via ftp. Hopefully this helps.
Thanks!